# testing if object implements the protocol

Tags: swift

Using unit testing framework,

```
var car: IVehicle = Vehicle.getInstance("mycar") //dictionary

XCTAssertNotNil(car, "Expecting instance not null")
```

didn't work, not sure why (results in "IVehicle does not conform to protocol AnyObject" compiler error).

But `car as Car` worked:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(car as Car, "Expecting instance not null")
```

This didn't work saying is test is always true, not sure how can we test for conformance of a protocol?

```
XCTAssertTrue(car is IVehicle, "Expecting instance implements IVehicle")
```

Comment: You should be more descriptive than "didn't work". There isn't only one way things can "not work".

Comment: For your `car as Car` case, it's because `as` cannot return `nil`. It will crash your program if the cast is invalid. Use `as?` if you want to get nil if the object isn't a Car.

Comment: If your class is a subclass of NSObject, you could check the conformance using the NSObject method, conformsToProtocol: method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly,

```
XCTAssertNotNil(car, "Expecting instance not null")
```

Assuming `IVehicle` is a protocol, the error you'll get is because that means it is not an `AnyObject` which is what `XCTAssertNotNil` requires as a first parameter (`AnyObject` can only represent classes, not structs or protocols).  This is perhaps a bit frustrating because `XCTAssertNotNil` suggests it is for testing if optionals are set to nil, but there you have it.

Next:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(car as Car, "Expecting instance not null")
```

This compiles, but it probably hasn’t “worked”... if `car` is ever not a `Car`, you will get a runtime exception and not an assertion failure.  This is because `car as Car` forces the compiler to treat the left-hand expression as the right-hand type no matter whether it is or not (assuming that is a valid cast under at least some circumstances – if it isn’t possible at all, you’ll get a compiler error).  If at runtime it isn’t a valid cast, you’ll get a runtime failure.

The way to safely cast `car` to a `Car` if you’re not sure, is with `as?`.  So this should give you the results you want:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(car as? Car, "Expecting instance not null")
```

This will result in `Some(car)` if it is indeed a `Car`, or `nil` if it isn’t, properly triggering the test assertion.

Alternatively you could just write:

```
XCTAssert(car is Car, "Expecting car to be a Car")
```

Finally,

```
car is IVehicle
```

is always true because the compiler knows the type of the car variable at compile time, and knows full well that it’s a `IVehicle` — that is its type.  So it assumes you wrote this by accident since it cannot possibly ever be false, and it tells you so.

Comment: hi guru :), need your help on this please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530724/swift-program-to-interface

Comment: While this is good for development, it makes TDD in Swift a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1):

If your class inherits from NSObject you can also use this: -

```
conforms(to aProtocol: Protocol) -> Bool
```

It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver conforms to a given protocol

for example: -

```
 XCTAssertTrue(sut.conforms(to: CXProviderDelegate.self))
```