# Determining protocol types at runtime

Tags: swift

How can we determine if protocol conforms to a specific subtype based on user provided instances, if it's not possible this way, any alternate solutions.

**API**

```
protocol Super {}

protocol Sub: Super {} //inherited by Super protocol

class Type1: Super {} //conforms to super protocol

class Type2: Type1, Sub {} //conforms to sub protocol
```

inside another API class

```
func store(closures: [() -> Super]) {
    self.closures = closures
}
```

when it's time to call

```
func go() {
    for closure in closures {
        var instance = closure()
        if instance is Super {
            //do something - system will behave differently
        } else { //it's Sub
            //do something else - system will behave differently
        }
    }
}
```

**users of the api**

```
class Imp1: Type1 {}
class Imp2: Type2 {}

var closures: [() -> Super] = [ { Imp1() }, { Imp2() } ]
store(closures)
```

my current workaround within API

```
func go() {
        for closure in closures {
            var instance = closure()
            var behavior = 0
            if instance as? Type2 != nil { //not so cool, should be through protocols
                behavior = 1         //instead of implementations
            }


            if behavior == 0 { //do something within the api,

            } else { //do something else within the api

            }

            //instance overriden method will be called 
            //but not important here to show, polymorphism works in here
            //more concerned how the api can do something different based on the types

        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you use an array of functions that return the object and not an array of the objects itself?

Comment: not sure if I got your question right, the users will be actually providing their own implementations of Parent, and Child classes, edited

Comment: yes, but the function could be `func go( instances: [Super])` and could be calles with `go( [Parent(), Child()])`. Would be simpler.

Comment: ok, got you, why I used closures, so they are actually not instantiated directly, I just tried to make the example simpler, the go is called by the API itself when a message is fired, editing again

Comment: so basically they are not instantiated immediately but at a later time

Answer (score 1):

You are jumping through a lot of hoops to manually recreate dynamic dispatch, i.e. one of the purposes of protocols and classes.  Try actually using real runtime polymorphism to solve your problem.

Take this code:

```
    if instance is Super {
        //do something
    } else { //it's Sub
        //do something else
    }
```

What you are saying is, if it’s a superclass, run the superclass method, else, run the subclass.  This is a bit inverted – normally when you are a subclass you want to run the subclass code not the other way around.  But assuming you turn it around to the more conventional order, you are essentially describing calling a protocol’s method and expecting the appropriate implementation to get called:

(the closures aren’t really related to the question in hand so ignoring them for now)

```
protocol Super { func doThing() }
protocol Sub: Super { }  // super is actually a bit redundant here

class Type1: Super {
    func doThing() {
        println("I did a super thing!")
    }
}

class Type2: Sub {
    func doThing() {
        println("I did a sub thing!")
    }
}

func doSomething(s: Super) {
    s.doThing()
}

let c: [Super] = [Type1(), Type2()]

for t in c {
    doSomething(t)
}

// prints “I did a super thing!”, then “I did a sub thing!"
```

Alternatives to consider: eliminate `Sub`, and have `Type2` inherit from `Type1`.  Or, since there’s no class inheritance here, you could use structs rather than classes.

Comment: actually it's not about calling overloaded when it's child or super method when it's parent, it's just that system will behave differently, let's say that behavior/mode is sync and async, I edited do something/something else part to elaborate

Comment: If you are trying to drive behaviour based on a runtime value, I recommend trying a variable.  You’re using types for the wrong purpose.

Comment: but types determine the runtime value and thus the behavior, edited func go

Answer (score 1):

Almost any time you find yourself wanting to use `is?`, you probably meant to use an enum. Enums allow you use to the equivalent of `is?` without feeling bad about it (because it isn't a problem). The reason that `is?` is bad OO design is that it creates a function that is closed to subtyping, while OOP itself is always open to subtyping (you should think of `final` as a compiler optimization, not as a fundamental part of types).

Being closed to subtyping is not a problem or a bad thing. It just requires thinking in a functional paradigm rather than an object paradigm. Enums (which are the Swift implementation of a Sum type) are exactly the tool for this, and are very often a better tool than subclassing.

```
enum Thing {
    case Type1(... some data object(s) ...)
    case Type2(... some data object(s) ...)
}
```

Now in `go()`, instead of an `is?` check, you `switch`. Not only is this not a bad thing, it's *required* and fully type-checked by the compiler.

(Example removes the lazy closures since they're not really part of the question.)

```
func go(instances: [Thing]) {
    for instance in instances {
        switch instance {
            case Type1(let ...) { ...Type1 behaviors... }
            case Type2(let ...) { ...Type2 behaviors... }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have some shared behaviors, just pull those out into a function. You're free to let your "data objects" implement certain protocols or be of specific classes if that makes things easier to pass along to shared functions. It's fine if `Type2` takes associated data that happens to be a subclass of `Type1`.

If you come along later and add a `Type3`, then the compiler will warn you about every `switch` that fails to consider this. That's why enums are safe while `is?` is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need objects derived from the Objective-C world to do this:

```
@objc protocol Super {}

@objc protocol Sub: Super {}

class Parent: NSObject, Super {}

class Child: NSObject, Sub {}

func go( closures: [() -> Super]) {
  for closure in closures {
    let instance = closure()
    if instance is Sub { // check for Sub first, check for Super is always true
      //do something
    } else {
      //do something else
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Version with different method implementations:

```
protocol Super {
  func doSomething()
}

protocol Sub: Super {}

class Parent: Super {
  func doSomething() {
    // do something
  }
}

class Child: Sub {
  func doSomething() {
    // do something else
  }
}

func go( closures: [() -> Super]) {
  for closure in closures {
    let instance = closure()
    instance.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt but don't wanna go there to objective-c world, there should be something we could do in here, btw thanks for helping me to refine the question

Comment: Native Swift objects don't support runtime inspection yet.

Comment: any workarounds, all I can think of is to add a method to child that says yes I'm child, and the api first calls that,.... but no.

Comment: my friend what do you say about `if (instance as? Type1) != nil {`

Comment: I get an error: `Cannot downcast from 'Super' to non-@obj protocol type 'Sub'`.

Comment: Btw, I think the canonical way to solve your problem would be to add a method `doSomething` to the `Super` protocol and do different things in the `Parent` and `Child` implementations.

Comment: for the downcast error, actually use `as? Parent` or `as? Child` but again it's not determination using protocols but specific implementations